# - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid url:

Tags: java

can u pls help me with last line URL error

```
Started by user venkat aynala
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Camera
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/venkat3636/Camera # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/venkat3636/Camera
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials github
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/venkat3636/Camera +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 5ee1a3a778cf0aaa1b0fa0fcffbb5d37746ae20f (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 5ee1a3a778cf0aaa1b0fa0fcffbb5d37746ae20f
Commit message: "InitialCommitingToCamera"
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 5ee1a3a778cf0aaa1b0fa0fcffbb5d37746ae20f # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[Camera] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation\Gradle_5.1\bin\gradle.bat"' && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 5.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
Gitcolony notification failed - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid url: 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: May be you should try disabling that plugin.

have a look at this issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29833

Comment: Could u pls tell me how to desable that plugin. And this is the correct way of build the project or not??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have repository url correct? It looks like, you clonned repository and someone change for example project name on repository.

Comment: Actually https://github.com/venkat3636/Camera returns a 404 status code

Comment: i think this is cause of problem